# Windows 7 no internet and no updates

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection

I use Windows 7 Ultimate as a host for VMWare Workstation. I run Windows 8 in a virtual machine.

A network cable with Internet is connected to the machine, Internet works fine from Virtual Machine.

So, host gets proper Internet address.

But I cannot access Internet on host and I cannot install update on host.

What can I check to figure out why I can't access Internet from the host?

Comment: Please check over your internet settings; can you ping your local router? can you do a nslookup for google?  Please have a look through this list:  http://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-7/windows-7-cannot-connect-to-internet/.  What anti-virus and firewall are you using?  Did you properly choose what type of network/network location?   http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/choosing-network-location#1TC=windows-7  http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/3473563/change-your-network-location-settings/

Answer (score 1):

To have an internet connection, you have to set the network to bridged or NAT.
If you use NAT, it automatically switches between wifi or ethernet, and is easiest, if you just want to use internet inside.
If you used bridged networking, you have to change settings whenever you switch between wifi and ethernet, but the virtual machine is connected to the network like a real machine, so you it has a local ip and can offer services to the network.

Just read the VMWare article about it, it will explain everything.

[VMWare Help on networking](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net.html)

Comment: Did this help you? No more question, so I assume you have found a solution?